# Hystrix Readed time out status 504 on first zuul call

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

I am always getting the "Hystrix Readed time out" error message for first ever call to zuul. I am using "Greenwich.RELEASE"  spring cloud version.

**I tried to include hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds: 5000 property in zuul's bootstrap.yml but it giving me error unknown property "hystrix.command".**

Below is the error logs.

```
2019-05-18 19:20:13.407  WARN 26204 --- [o-55001-exec-10] o.s.c.n.z.filters.post.SendErrorFilter   : Error during filtering

com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: 
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run(SendErrorFilter.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:117) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:193) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:157) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.error(FilterProcessor.java:105) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.error(ZuulRunner.java:112) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.error(ZuulServlet.java:145) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.service(ZuulServlet.java:83) [zuul-core-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:165) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.web.ZuulController.handleRequest(ZuulController.java:44) [spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:52) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1038) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:998) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:875) [spring-webmvc-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) [tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.web.trace.servlet.HttpTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpTraceFilter.java:90) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:154) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.filterAndRecordMetrics(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:122) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:107) [spring-boot-actuator-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.1.2.RELEASE.jar:5.1.2.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:770) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1415) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_172]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_172]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.12.jar:9.0.12]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_172]
```

Comment: I recently met with the same issue. just override below timeout values. `hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=150000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=150000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=150000`

Comment: Please check this link stackoverflow.com/a/44918316/9183844

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-netflix/1.4.2.RELEASE/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#_zuul_timeouts), you need to use some properties.

I tried this and works to me:

```
zuul.host.socket-timeout-millis=20000
zuul.host.connect-timeout-millis=20000
ribbon.ConnectTimeout=10000
ribbon.ReadTimeout=10000
```